# React native- Best way to create singleton pattern

Tags: reactjs, react-native, singleton

I am new in react-native coding but have experienced on objective-c and swift coding and want use singleton pattern in react-native.
I have tried to find out the solution from other StackOverflow answer but most of them are creating only singleton functions as below code:

```js
var Singleton = (function () {
    var instance;

    function createInstance() {
        var object = new Object("I am the instance");
        return object;
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();

function run() {

    var instance1 = Singleton.getInstance();
    var instance2 = Singleton.getInstance();

    alert("Same instance? " + (instance1 === instance2));  
}
```

As we can see in above code here we are creating singleton function not class.
Please let me know if any way to create singleton class and pass multiple variables in that class as objective-c or swift.
Note: Please also notify me if I am going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's my implementation for singleton class...

Controller.js

```js
export default class Controller {
    static instance = Controller.instance || new Controller()

    helloWorld() {
        console.log("Hello World... \(^_^)/ !!")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```js
import Controller from 'Controller.js'

Controller.instance.helloWorld()
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `static sharedInstance = Controller.sharedInstance == null ? new Controller() : Controller.sharedInstance` due to the `static`?

Answer (score 15):

You can use something like that

```js
 class SingletonClass {

  static instance = null;
  static createInstance() {
      var object = new SingletonClass();
      return object;
  }

  static getInstance () {
      if (!SingletonClass.instance) {
          SingletonClass.instance = SingletonClass.createInstance();
      }
      return SingletonClass.instance;
  }
}

var instance1 = SingletonClass.getInstance();
var instance2 = SingletonClass.getInstance();
```

Comment: How would you access that same instance from different components?

Comment: You can write this code at the end of the singleton class:

const singletonClass =  SingletonClass.getInstance();
export default singletonClass

Then import the the file with any other component

Answer (score -8):

The singleton pattern isn't used much in the JS ecosystem. What you should look into is http://mobx.js.org. MobX is a library that allows you to create observable objects to store data for your apps. You instantiate one store for each domain you please and make edits to that store to change app state.