# Signleton between different components in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, singleton, components

I want to have some object to be accessible from multiple components, the same object, and those components are independent of each other.

It looks like Redux isn't the right way and this: [React native- Best way to create singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023879/react-native-best-way-to-create-singleton-pattern) doesn't really answer the question.

Is there another way?

Comment: Why do think Redux isn't the right way? Also is this object going be constant or change over time inside your application?

Comment: The state of that object might change. Is Redux a good fit for this? @DhruvParmar

Comment: Definitely yes, Redux provides a single state store for your entire application. Any changes to this store are triggered via Actions and state changes are commited inside Reducer functions. 
It looks to me Redux is the way to go for you here, since you would probably want to listen for updates to this singleton object too?

Comment: You should consider redux if (a) you're already using redux to store other state or (b) if your app merits introducing redux anyway. The latter is a matter of judgement. If you're not ready to introduce redux, create your shared object (not really a singleton in this case) in the container component which is the nearest common ancestor of all the components it's needed in. Then push it down through props. If this becomes unwieldy (because of having to push the object through many levels which don't use it) then that's a sign to start thinking about redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure this is right way but I usually do this way through module.

```js
// config.js
export default {
    data1: 'data1',
    data2: 'data2',
    ...
}

// from components

import Config from './config' // You can do this easier with @providesModule
...
config.data1 // you now access & modify common datas like this
```

Comment: It's a complex object that I also need to configure (a Firebase object), not just strings. So you suggest to write a wrapper file for it?

Comment: You can store & configure complex objects too as it is javascript.

Comment: Is each `import` imports the same object or a copy? How can I know if the object I'm working with is the same across different components?

Comment: There's no copy, or create another one. It will be compiled only once.