# how to handle heavy API request without blocking the UI in react native

Tags: react-native

i have some heavy API request made through my app. so i want to implement feature that if user hit any API request then after user should navigate through any screen but there is some loading icon indicating that API request is in progress.

For example :-

if user is in create-product screen and after clicking on create product button user should navigate through any screen like profile,,product-view or any other screen while API request is processing but i want to show some loading indicator from any screen that API request is in progress in background.

Comment: Use ActivityIndicator you can import it like, `import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native' `

Comment: use InteractionManager

Comment: i want to show some loading indicator while navigating to any-screen if any API request is running in background. and i don't want to include ActivityIndicator in every screen. is there any option to include LOADING INDICATOR in APP.JS and show it in any-screen in my app.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a singleton
Which is

A design pattern that ensures that exactly one application-wide instance of a particular class exists. One of the Gang of Four's creational design patterns.

I recommend you read more about it
It will be useful for your case
Here is how to make it with react native
[React native- Best way to create singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023879/react-native-best-way-to-create-singleton-pattern)