# call class function from export const react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to call handleSend function in ComposeBox.js from export const class in webViewEventHandlers.js

> ComposeBox.js

```
class ComposeBox extends PureComponent<Props, State> {

handleSend = () => {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    const { message } = this.state;
    dispatch(addToOutbox(this.getDestinationNarrow(), message));

    this.setMessageInputValue('');
  };

export default connect((state: GlobalState, props) => ({
  auth: getAuth(state),
}))(ComposeBox);
```

> webViewEventHandlers.js

```
import ComposeBox from '../compose/ComposeBox';

export const handleMessageListEvent = () => {

case 'wizrep':
      ComposeBox.handleSend();
      break;
```

I got the following error

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188551/react-native-how-to-call-a-function-from-another-class-wrapped-connect-in-reac)

Comment: Thanks bro, but it works only on static function.

Comment: I kinda understand what u trying to do. But remember one thing. If you would like to call a function of a class you need to have an instance of it. For examle `class Foo{function method(){//do smth}}   class Boo { function meth(){ var a = new Foo(); a.method();}}`

Comment: I tried to implement your example

`case 'wizrep':
      var test = new ComposeBox();
      test.handleSend();
      break;`

Cannot read property 'store' of undefined

Comment: yes redux I guess causes this error. I think you have better find a new approach to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The React manual states that: [**All React components must act like pure functions with respect to their props.**](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only)

Which means trying to create an instance of a Component and treating it as an object will give you a really hard time.

Based on the snippet of code you send, I can imagine a few possible workarounds:

- Call handleMessageListEvent from inside ComposeBox, passing the handleSend function as an argument.
- Set message as part of your Redux state instead of the component, and dispatch the action from webViewEventHandlers.
- Make handleMessageListEvent part of the ComposeBox component.