# How to update state from other component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react native and react navigation for routing.

How to update state from another component/page?

HomeScreen

```
export class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
      test: ''
    }
  }

  updateState = ()=>{
    this.setState({test:'new value'});
  }

 }



SideMenuScreen
import { HomeScreen } from "./home"; 

export class SideMenuScreen extends Component {

  updateHomeState = ()=>{
    let oHome = new HomeScreen(); 
    oHome.updateState();
  }

}
```

My App.js and routing and sidemenu config as below :

```
import { createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { SideMenuScreen } from "./screens/Sidemenu";
import { HomeScreen } from "./screens/Home";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <AppContainer></AppContainer>
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {Home: HomeScreen, 
    other: otherpage},
  {
    contentComponent: SideMenuScreen
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

updateState executing but not updating state.

Comment: Do you render SideMenuScreen inside HomeScreen?

Comment: No sidemenuscreen in content component

Comment: So there is no parent-child relationship between two components, right?

Comment: can you check question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not haveing Parent-Child relationship between your components ... thi s could be accomplished through **Redux Action**

```
HomeScreen;

export class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      test: ""
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { test: nextTest } = nextProps;
    const { test } = this.props;

    if (nextTest !== test) {
        this.setState({ test: nextTest });
    }
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = ({ yourReducerName: test }) => ({ test });
export connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen);

import { HomeScreen } from "./home";
import { connect } from "tls";

class SideMenuScreen extends Component {
  updateHomeState = () => {
    const { updateHomeStateAction } = this.props;

    updateHomeStateAction({ test: 'New Value' });
  };
}

export default connect(null, { updateHomeStateAction })(SideMenuScreen);
```

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari Redux is really the way to go for this kind of problem. https://redux.js.org/basics/basic-tutorial

Comment: I tried a lot but i can't find solution. Now I am going use redux can suggest simple redux example

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari `redux` is a very powerful tool ... I guess it'd be great if you could invest sometime learning it ... not just for the use case at hand now, but also for many use cases that I believe you're going to face ...

However, redux is kind of not easy to understand at the begining ... but once you get the hang of it, it'll be very very easy to setup and use...

For free tutorials:
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=redux+tutorial

For Paid ones (which I highly recommend) ... Steve Grider in udemy
https://www.udemy.com/user/sgslo/

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari Best of luck!

Answer (score 5):

> If you have to update from the child component

You will have to pass down the `Handlers` from the component which holds the **state** to update the values, child component can make use of these handlers to update the **state**

> If you have to update from some other location

You will have to do a **[level up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)** the State and follow the same has above.

**LevelUpComponent**

```
export class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
      test: ''
    }
  }

  updateState = (values)=>{
    this.setState(values);
  }

  render(){
    return <div>
     <HomeScreen></HomeScreen>
     <SideMenuScreen updateState={this.updateState}></SideMenuScreen>
     </div>
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but there is not parent child relation

Comment: I want to change state from side menu.

Comment: Not the answer that the OP was looking for, but absolutely the answer I was, so +1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

when you navigate to next screen pass this function in params,

```
this.props.navigate("SideMenuScreen",{update:this.updateState});
```

And in your side menu screen,
 call it using props,

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.update();//you can pass params also if needed
```

Comment: I am opening sidemenu like this.props.navigation.openDrawer()

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using ref.

```
HomeScreen 

export class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
      test: ''
    }
  }

  updateState = ()=>{
    this.setState({test:'new value'});
  }

 }



SideMenuScreen
import { HomeScreen } from "./home"; 

export class SideMenuScreen extends Component {

  updateHomeState = ()=>{
    this.homeScreen.updateState();
  }

render(){
return(
<HomeScreen ref={(ele) => this.homeScreen = ele}/>
);
}

}
```