# How to play audio from array in another class in react-native

Tags: react-native

I wanted to play audios in a class but the audio is from an array that placed in another class in react-native.

I Have an app  for study about audio, array, and list. I can already show the subject and name in the list and in the class to play the audio. But I don't know how to play the different audio from the arraylist. I expect it like a playlist but I never found a tutorial to do that. Can you help me about this?

this is in the array.js where I put the array of music

```
export default [

    {
        user:'song1',
        subject:'euphoria',
        name:'euphoria',
        audio: require('../src/musics/euphoria.mp3')
    },

    {
        subject:'tempo',
        user:'song2',
        name:'tempo',
        audio: require('../src/musics/tempo.mp3')

    },

    {
        user:'song4',
        subject:'thanks',
        name:'thanks',

        audio: require('../src/musics/thanks.mp3')

    }
]
```

and this is the ehe.js where I want to play the music

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import  SoundPlayer from 'react-native-sound-player';
import array from './array'

// create a component

class Ehe extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            pencet:()=>SoundPlayer.playSoundFile({audio}),
        }
    }
    klik=()=>{
        SoundPlayer.pause()
        this.setState({
            pencet:()=>SoundPlayer.resume()
        })
    }
    kliik=()=>{
         SoundPlayer.stop()
         this.setState({
             pencet:()=>SoundPlayer.playSoundFile({audio})
     })
    }
    render() {
        const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
        const subject = params ? params.subject : null;
        const audio = params ? params.audio : null;

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.judul}>{subject}</Text>

                <View style={styles.audio}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.klik}>
                    <Image source={require('../src/image/pausee.png')} style={{width:60, height: 60, marginRight:5, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.state.pencet}>
                    <Image source={require('../src/image/playy.png')} style={{width:60, height: 60, marginRight:5, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

What Should I do to play /stop/pause/resume the audio from the array.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes sure, You can create a class and do what ever functions you want and then export it
Let says you want to simple class as follows:

```
import  SoundPlayer from 'react-native-sound-player';
class PlayMySound {}
PlayMySound.soundsArray = [

    {
        user:'song1',
        subject:'euphoria',
        name:'euphoria',
        audio: require('../src/musics/euphoria.mp3')
    },

    {
        subject:'tempo',
        user:'song2',
        name:'tempo',
        audio: require('../src/musics/tempo.mp3')

    },

    {
        user:'song4',
        subject:'thanks',
        name:'thanks',

        audio: require('../src/musics/thanks.mp3')

    }
]
PlayMySound.play = (soundID) => {
 ... Your code to search for the audio file in the previous array..
 SoundPlayer.playSoundFile({audio})
}

PlayMySound.stop = (soundID) => {
 ... Your code to search for the audio file int the previous array..
}
.....
export default PlayMySound;
```

Then in your main file `ehe.js` you can import the class and use the static functions

```
import PlayMySound from './playMySound.js';
//You can use the functions you create in the class
PlayMySound.play(audio_ID)
```

You can also follow this answer for more information
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48727463/1627358

Hopefully this will resolve your issue.