# How to fix 'undefined is not an object' when using OnPress

Tags: react-native

I have added a Call button to a screen in a drawer navigation. 
However, even though I have binded 'this', so as to keep its context, when I press the Call button, I receive an "undefined is not an object (evaluating _this6.App.dialCall.
Here is the relevent code:

```
    render() {  
    return (  
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "black", alignItems: 
  'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>  


            <Text style={{backgroundColor: "black", fontSize: 16, color: 
         "white"}}>Dour services are available 24 hours a day, so you can 
    truly rely on us.

 We will match or try and beat any price. 

                  </Text>
                   <Button  title='Call' onPress={() => 
       this.App.dialCall.bind(this)}
                 /> 

               </View>  
                );
```

(this is on the Home Screen in the drawer navigation.
My function is in the main class:

```
  export default class App extends Component {
     dialCall = () => {

         let phoneNumber = '';

          if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
           phoneNumber = 'tel:${1234567890}';
          }
         else {
           phoneNumber = 'telprompt:${1234567890}';
         }

          Linking.openURL(phoneNumber);
        };

      render() {  
         return <AppContainer />;  
      }  
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using function/methods from different class then you have to call that child class let's say class A in the parent class let's say class B in it's constructor as an object.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
this.objectOfChildClass = new App();
    this.state = {
    };
  }
```

After doing this access the methods by using `this.objectOfChildClass.functionName`

Also you don't need to bind the function when you are already using fat arrow function. It does the same what bind does.

[Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648440/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-class-in-react-native)

Comment: Actually, I did that, as follows, but it came up with "Type error - undefined is not an object, evaluating _this%.dialcall.bind

Comment: class DashboardScreen extends Component { 
 
          static navigationOptions = {  
               title: 'Home',  
         };  
         constructor(props) {
            super(props);
             this.dialCall = this.dialCall.bind (this);
          }

Comment: Also you don't need to bind the function when you are already using fat arrow function. It does the same what bind does.

Comment: <Button  title='Call' onPress={() => this.dialCall}

Comment: `class DashboardScreen extends Component { static navigationOptions = { title: 'Home', }; constructor(props) { super(props); this.objectOfChildClass = new App(); }`

Comment: So just onPress = this.dialCall then??

Comment: Now access the function as : `<Button title='Call' onPress={() => this.objectOfChildClass.dialCall()}`

Comment: If it works, please accept the answer so others might also be helped if they face same problem.

Comment: Just one last question - what would be objectofchildclass om this case??

Comment: objectofchildclass is already an instance of the `App` class.  `this.objectOfChildClass = new App();` Using this will create a instance of the App class through which you can access all the information in App class. Don't forget to import the App class in your Home Class