# Calling Function from Another Class React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to call a function from another class. All i need is when i press the button it should console log an output to my browser.I tried making some steps but it throws an error saying "Cannot read property of message". Here's my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
import messageClass from "./message"

class App extends Component{

 onPress = ()=>{
  this.setState({FromStr: this.state.From})
  this.setState({ToStr: this.state.To})
  messageClass.message()
 }

 render(){
  return (
   <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
     <Button
       title={"Press"}
       color="#FFFFFF"
       onPress={this.onPress}
     />
   </View> 
  );
 }
}
```

message.js

```
import { Component } from "react";
export default class messageClass  extends Component{
    message(){
        console.log("Hiiiii")
    }
}
```

Comment: check this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648440/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-class-in-react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648440/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-class-in-react-native)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use static method ?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
import messageClass from "./MessageClass"

export default class App extends Component{
     onPress = ()=>{
        messageClass.message()
     };

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={{width:100, height:50}}>
                <Button
                    title={"Press"}
                    color="#FFFFFF"
                    onPress={this.onPress}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

```
import { Component } from "react";

export default class messageClass  extends Component{
    static message(){
        console.log("foo")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you imported messageClass.js to App.js properly ?

Comment: How can i call it without "static" because state wont let me to change the state of my program

Comment: If you want to change state from another parent class you should use redux to manage your data and control your states with shoudlComponentUpdate() function I'd recommend you to check these out; https://redux.js.org  and   https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html