# How to be able to use a method outside its class in a function React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm having a hard time executing a class method outside of it and in a function

```
class Player extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  test(){
    console.log('test')
  }

}
export default Player;
```

what I tried to do:

```
function() {
 Player.test();
}

class Player extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 }

 test(){
  console.log('test')
 }

}
export default Player;
```

I tried several ways to run this method in the function but it didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a function from another class in React-Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648440/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-class-in-react-native)

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you have to include `Player` inside the `render` of the class which you want to execute it. Then, set a `ref` to that `Player` component and then call your function through the `ref`.

Here is a working example...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';


class Player extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  test(){
    console.log('test')
  }

  render() {
    return(
      null
    )
  }
}


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.Player.test()
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>Test</Text>
        <Player ref={component => this.Player = component}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, but thank you very much for your help and willingness

Comment: but I just have a doubt, this example you did I needed this app class to be a function and not a class, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try using static methods:

`The static keyword defines a static method for a class. Static methods aren't called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on the class itself. These are often utility functions, such as functions to create or clone objects.`

```
class ClassWithStaticMethod {
  static staticMethod() {
    return 'static method has been called.';
  }
}

console.log(ClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod());
// expected output: "static method has been called."
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Answer (score 0):

My question is: do you need Player to be a Component? If you don't, just do:

```
function() {
 new Player().test();
}

class Player {
 test(){
  console.log('test')
 }
}

export default Player;
```

Comment: I'm using a music player library and it was built as a class, but my app I developed in the form of functions. So I needed that I could use methods that are within the library class within my functions

Answer (score 0):

**Create Player class object in App class**

```
var obj = new Player();

now access method with the help of obj

obj.test();
```