# Access function from another class component

Tags: reactjs

I have two siblings class components and I am trying to call a function with arguments that resides in the PMtoXX from the XYtoPM.
I am stuck of how to pass on the parameters and invoke the function. I get the error that the plot_PMSegment expected one argument.

`
PMtoXY.tsx

```
class PMtoXY extends Component<IProps> {
----
plot_PMSegment = (beg_routeid, end_routeid) => {
-----
}
}

export default PMtoXY;
```

and I have this sibling component that I am trying to call the PMtoXY function from it.

XYtoPM.tsx
`

```
class XYtoPM extends Component<IProps> {

import PMtoXY from "./PMtoXY";
----
-----
new plot_PMSegment(therouteid, theend_routeid)
-----
export default XYtoPM
```

Comment: Since React has ``uni-directional, top to bottom`` approach, straightforward solution is not possible.. Use can use either the ``Parent Component`` of both siblings or use ``Context`` API instead

Comment: A quick read could help you .. https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/communicating-between-sibling-react-hook-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer from one of the suggestions (not the answer) provided on this posting:
[How to call a function from another class in React-Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648440/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-class-in-react-native)

The suggestion was:
"You dont initiate your class, to solve this you need to change the B.abc() to new B().abc();"